# modify the columns

Tags: linux, shell, awk, scripting, columns

This is my dataset:

```
chr1_KI270706v1_random,153401,rs867658023,chr1_KI270706v1_random_153401
chr1_KI270706v1_random,154751,rs1030747857,chr1_KI270706v1_random_154751
chr1_KI270706v1_random,156703,rs900345029,chr1_KI270706v1_random_156703
chr1_KI270706v1_random,156856,rs576837150,chr1_KI270706v1_random_156856
```

I actually want it to be like:

```
chr1,153401,rs1867658023,chr1_153401
```

Basically I want to remove the extra value like `_KI_random` from column 1 and column 4.
I tried this command but I am not getting the desired output:

```
awk 'NR >1 {split($1, array, "_"); print array[1] "_" array[2]; split($2, array, "_"); print array[1] "_" array[2]}' outfile > rsid_final1.csv
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: One way is to use `sed` or another suitable tool to remove `_KI270706v1_random`. Then, `awk` seems to be the ideal tool to combine $1 and $2 to create $4.

Comment: Your own `awk` code skips the first line of input.  Is this because there's some header there? It is not shown in your data.  Also, it wouldb e _trivial_ to remove the `_KI270706v1_random` string from each line with `sed 's/_KI270706v1_random//g'`, but it would need to be more complex if the string that should be removed is not static.  Is it static?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a simple substitution on individual lines I'd just use sed:

```
$ sed 's/_KI[^_,]*_[^_,]*//g' file
chr1,153401,rs867658023,chr1_153401
chr1,154751,rs1030747857,chr1_154751
chr1,156703,rs900345029,chr1_156703
chr1,156856,rs576837150,chr1_156856
```

but you can do the same with awk if you prefer:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/_KI[^_,]*_[^_,]*/,"")} 1' file
chr1,153401,rs867658023,chr1_153401
chr1,154751,rs1030747857,chr1_154751
chr1,156703,rs900345029,chr1_156703
chr1,156856,rs576837150,chr1_156856
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output including cases where the above doesn't work.